# limit a list of tags to one category

Tags: categories, tags, list

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I am attempting to limit a list of tags to one category, in a couple different spots on my web page. I have this code:

```
    <?php
    $tags = get_tags();
    $tags_count = count($tags);
    $percolumn = ceil($tags_count / 3);

    for ($i = 0;$i < $tags_count;$i++):
    if ($i < $percolumn):
    $tag_left .= '
<li><a href="'. get_tag_link($tags[$i]->term_id) . '"rel="tag">' . $tags[$i]->name .'</a></li>
    ' . "\n";
    elseif ($i >= $percolumn && $i < $percolumn*2):
    $tag_mid .= '
<li><a href="'. get_tag_link($tags[$i]->term_id) . '"rel="tag">' . $tags[$i]->name .'</a></li>
    ' . "\n";
    elseif ($i >= $percolumn*2):
    $tag_right .= '
<li><a href="'. get_tag_link($tags[$i]->term_id) . '"rel="tag">' . $tags[$i]->name .'</a></li>
    ' . "\n";
    endif;
    endfor;
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php echo $tag_left; ?>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <?php echo $tag_mid; ?>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <?php echo $tag_right; ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I leverage this, and restrict the query to just one category.

Comment: You say one category, but yet you are using get_tags which only deals with post_tags.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without a plugin, but you would need to get all the posts with that specific category and then loop through those to get the tags of each of those specific posts.

Comment: I am a little new to php, and trying to wrap my head around all of this. Do you have any documentation you could point me towards to get this started? Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind I found the appropriate code here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5321373

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do this exact thing a day or two ago. I ended up using the plugin/widget: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-taxonomy/

It allows you to create custom taxonomies, and includes a tag cloud/list limited to whatever category you choose. And other things, but I've only used those two. Easy to style with CSS and worked right away.

Hope that helps.

Comment: dmoz do you know if this plugin allows me to do this on different pages to different categories, or is it a one size fits all.

Comment: Kevin I am trying to list out the posts from a single category. For example, I have category x, and I want all the tags that are associated with category x only.

Comment: Apologies, I meant the SensitiveTagCloud: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sensitive-tag-cloud/